# Android: Unable to start an activity upon selection a contextmenu item

Tags: android

I want to open the aboutActivity upon selecting the contextmenu item but nothing happens when I select any item from the contextmenu.

Here is the code:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menu){
        // get menu id
        int menuid = menu.getItemId();
        switch (menuid){
        case 0:
            Intent intnt2 = new Intent(ListActivity.this,aboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intnt2);
        break;
        case 1:
            Intent intnt3 = new Intent(ListActivity.this,aboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intnt3);
        break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(menu);
    }
```

I have declared the aboutActivity in manifest file and I have another menu item(named "About") which lauches the aboutActivity.Any help?

[Edit]
This is the onCreateContextMenu function:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View view,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        //checking if the long press is coming from ListView or not
        if(view.getId()==R.id.mainlist){
            //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo ainfo= (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Item menu");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"Edit");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,0,"Delete");
        }
    }
```

How to use R.id here,as raghunandan suggested?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in here to make see if the method gets called? Did you register the `View`?

Comment: Should it not be 
         `switch (menuid){
          case R.id.id1:`

Comment: are U using actionbarsherlock ?

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
      switch (menuid){
      case R.id.id1:
        Intent intnt2 = new Intent(ListActivity.this,aboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intnt2);
        return true;
       case R.id.id2:
        Intent intnt3 = new Intent(ListActivity.this,aboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intnt3);
        return true;
       default:
       return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
       }
```

`public boolean onContextItemSelected` // return type is of boolean

Edit:

```
  switch (menuid){
  case 0:
    Intent intnt2 = new Intent(ListActivity.this,aboutActivity.class);
    startActivity(intnt2);
    return true;
    ....
   default:
   return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
   }
```

Comment: I did what you have suggested but used hardcode numbers instead on R.id and nothing happened on selecting the menu item.

Comment: @RajatSaxena `onCreateContextMenu` log some info in your if condition check if it works.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you?

Comment: does the if condition work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389184/oncreatecontextmenu-and-listview-items.

Comment: I see no If condition in that link?

Comment: i asked in your code does the if condition work. i posted the link as a side note for your reference.

Comment: there is no IF condition in my code.Are you talking about Switch statement?

Comment: `if(view.getId()==R.id.mainlist){` does this work in your code? I don't know if i can help further. wait for a better suggestion or answer. Good luck.

Comment: Yes,I'm getting the context menu with "Edit" and "Delete" options but nothing happens when I select either of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a wild guess, but I'd check the menu item IDs. I'd be really surprised if they are 0 and 1; and in general, you shouldn't hardcode numbers, but use the `R` class constants.