# How to use onCreateContextMenu and onContextItemSelected with linear Layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to use `onCreateContextMenu` function and `onContextItemSelected` function for selecting a row from linear Layout with 2 `TextBoxes` in it.

What I am not able to understand is which ID to pass for `registerForContextMenu()`.
Should I pass the ID of the `TextBoxes` or the `LinearLaout`?

I tried doing both but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but if your only want an example of usage see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16872778/3882134)